# best way to used stylesheet in our project in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am working on reactjs project.I am facing one issue regarding performance .Example I am using a external stylesheet `https://xyx/abc.css`.So Added in HTML head tag like that `<link href="..url"`/>. Now My issue is this is huge file or large number of css class are there , but I am using only few classes let example `10`.So to improve the performance I downloaded this css file `locally` in my project inside `css` directory and using `webpack` I remove the unused file.

Now the problem is that huge external `css` file update in a week or `2 week` regularly.So if Downloaded that file locally I will not get updated code of `css` file. so it is manual work to download css file after `2` week.

is there any better approach to `purge css` or `remove unused css` from external sheet without saving the file `locally`.

Can you please tell approach what to do ?

Comment: There may be a better solution, but it's technically possible to make dynamic changes to stylesheets programatically using JavaScript. So you could write a custom script to, say,  remove every rule that doesn't match certain criteria. You'd apply your custom script to each new version of the stylesheet and use the modified version on your server.

Comment: Use a server-side solution. Your React app loads a local stylesheet, but not just a static file, the request actually runs a script that downloads the external one and removes the noise before sending it back to the browser. Of course the server doesn't do that each time the stylesheet is requested, it caches the reduced version until a new version goes online at the remote site.

Comment: so how I will `pursecss` or `removecss` from server

Comment: You're doing it manually right now, correct? If you want to automate it, you have to write a script that determines whether a rule is needed or not, then removes unused rules. I don't have enough information to be more specific.